# Why does a Fernet encryption token always start with the same sequence? (Python Cryptography package)

Tags: python, cryptography

I've been playing around with the [Cryptography package](https://cryptography.io/), and the [Fernet (symmetric encryption) module](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/).

When encrypting some text like:

```
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)
token = f.encrypt(b"some random text")
```

The token always starts with the same sequence of bytes like this: `"gAAAABU80....."`.

Why is this?

Comment: What does the documentation you linked to say? It's only like 10 lines, read the last 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can gather from reading [the source code](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/_modules/cryptography/fernet/#Fernet.encrypt), the encrypted payload has the following structure:

```
b"\x80" + struct.pack(">Q", current_time) + iv + ciphertext
```

and what you get back from `encrypt` is the base64 encoding of the payload.

The first byte is `0x80`, hardcoded. The following 8 bytes are a 64bit timestamp, in big-endian order. Since it's a timestamp, the most significant bytes will change slowly over time. Big-endian is ordered MSB to LSB, so those "sticky" bytes are the first you will encounter when reading the string.

Base64 (partial) string `gAAAABU80` encodes 54bits, which is almost 7 bytes. So, that part encodes the `0x80` magic and the 6 MSBs of the timestamp, those that will change slower over time. Wait a few hours before encrypting a new message and you will see the header change.

Comment: First byte encodes the version of Fernet (currently always 0x80 for version 0, as indicated in the answer).

Comment: thank you! in the future i'll dig through the source code on my own first. really appreciate the help.